# Dynamic Columns - SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Having two tables, I want to convert some rows to columns. My database engine is Microsoft SQL Server. The image below illustrates my desired result.

[image: View Image Tables]

Comment: There are so many questions on here about dynamic pivots. Have you *looked* at any of them? Tried out any of the techniques? If so, please link to the one(s) you've already looked at and then your attempt to use them and what's not working. This isn't a "here's a spec, please write the code for me" service.

Comment: Search `dynamic pivot`

Comment: @configbug FYI there is a spanish version of stackoverflow, you may want to ask questions over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to what I needed. I share with you I made use of SQL STUFF:

```
SELECT A.codEmpresa
        ,A.nomEmpresa
        ,A.codSistema
        ,A.nomSistema
        ,A.codPerfil
        ,A.nomPerfil
        ,modulos = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + M.nomModulo
                                FROM smpseg.[0004] R
                                JOIN smpseg.[0014] SMOP
                                ON SMOP.codSistema = R.codSistema
                                AND SMOP.codModulo = R.codModulo
                                AND SMOP.codPerfil = A.codPerfil
                                AND SMOP.objDefault = CAST(1 AS BIT)
                                JOIN smpseg.[0011] O
                                ON O.codSistema = SMOP.codSistema
                                AND O.codModulo = SMOP.codModulo
                                AND O.codObjeto = SMOP.codObjeto
                                JOIN smpseg.[0010] M
                                ON M.codSistema = O.codSistema
                                AND M.codModulo = O.codModulo
                            WHERE R.codUsuario = @p_codUsuario
                                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') FROM smpseg.[0004] A
        JOIN smpseg.[0016] U
            ON U.codUsuario = A.codUsuario
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not so clear, but it seems you want to use [SQL PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot)

**Sample Data**

```
DECLARE @tblModule TABLE(modId INT,name VARCHAR(200))
DECLARE @tblProfile TABLE(id INT,modId INT,profil VARCHAR(200))

INSERT INTO @tblModule
SELECT 1,'Manteniminento' UNION
SELECT 2 , 'Soporte'

INSERT INTO @tblProfile
SELECT 1,1,'Administrador' UNION
SELECT 2,2 , 'Empleado' UNION
SELECT 3,1 , 'Empleado' UNION
SELECT 4,1 , 'Empleado' UNION
SELECT 5,1 , 'Administrador' UNION
SELECT 6,1 , 'Administrador'
```

**Main query**

```
SELECT name,SUM([Administrador]) AS Administrador, SUM([Empleado]) AS Empleado
FROM  
(SELECT id,p.modId,m.name,p.profil   
    FROM @tblProfile p
    INNER JOIN @tblModule m ON m.modId = p.modId) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
COUNT(modId)  
FOR profil IN ([Administrador], [Empleado])  
) AS PivotTable 
GROUP BY name
```

**Result**

```
name            Administrador   Empleado
Manteniminento  3               2
Soporte         0               1
```